# What does "as poll nears" mean?

Tags: phrases, headline-english

I just read The Jakarta Post
I've got this:

> "Prabowo changes style in campaign as poll nears"

what is the meaning of 'as poll nears', I've got some guesswork and I am not really sure about it, does that mean "the method to get the polling"?

Comment: "Poll" here means the actual official vote, the only one that counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese). Two of the characteristics of headlinese are:

- omission of articles
- use of short words of roughly the right meaning, even if they would not be used in ordinary writing (*poll* for *election*).

Answer (score 2):

*as poll nears* : as the poll (vote) approaches in time